# DB-less, single-PHP app to generate photo gallery?

Tags: untagged

Occasionally, I need to create a photo gallery on a LAMP server.

I'd like to find a no-brainer app that consists in a single PHP file, doesn't require a DB, and is able to create thumbnails the first time it's ran (it's OK if I have to manually call the app to pregenerate the thumbnails eg. `www.acme.com/gallery/index.php?initialize=yes`

Does someone know of an application that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Single File PHP Gallery](http://sye.dk/sfpg/).

No database, thumbnail creation on the fly.

It won't of course ever be a fast has having a DB.

Comment: Thanks guys. Single File PHP Gallery is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[MiniShowCase](http://minishowcase.net/) may suit your needs it is pretty simple and straightforward to make it work but is has many php files.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't quite fit the "single file" requirement, but [Gallery1](http://codex.gallery2.org/Downloads) is much lighter than Gallery2, and doesn't require a database.